# How to find Cohen's f for multiple regression with interaction included?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, effect-size

I am currently investigating the moderating role of mindfulness in the association between academic distress and suicide ideation with depression as a control variable. I finished doing the multiple regression analysis where all the IVs, control variable, and interaction term was regressed into suicide ideation in this particular format:

Depression Beta coefficinet
Academic Distress Beta coefficient
Mindfulness Beta coefficient
Academic Distress X Mindfulness Beta coefficient

My supervisor asked me to convert the score into Cohen's f to find the exact effect size of each predictor included in the analysis. My question is:
Can someone guide me on how to transform each IV into their appropriate Cohen's f? Is there any specific guide on how to do it? I tried finding Youtube videos for it. However, they only teach me how to do the effect size as a whole regression, not per IVs included in the regression.

Comment: I would suggest asking your supervisor to point you to an example of a publication that did such predictor-specific uses of Cohen's _f_. That doesn't seem to be standard, based on descriptions in [this UCLA page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/effect-size-power/faqhow-is-effect-size-used-in-power-analysis/)  and [this Cross Validated page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/507959/28500). A potentially useful effect size for a predictor might be the ratio of its coefficient to the standard deviation _of the predictor values_, but that's not Cohen's _f_.