How can I convert an effect size from Cohen's d to f(v)
I am interested in calculating the power I need to compare several groups to one reference group in how much an outcome changes between two timepoints. My understanding is that I should use the ANOVA: repeated measures, within-between interaction test with the additional "As in Cohen (1988) - recommended" option selected. However, I don't know what f(v) means -- all I know is, were this a simple t-test, I would be targeting a Cohen's D of 0.15. Can I convert from Cohen's D to f(v)?


It seems under options you changed the default to "as in Cohen (1988) - recommended", which changed the effect size from "Effect size f" to "Effect size f(V)". Assuming that this has to be an effect size defined by Cohen I searched for Cohen's f and found the following post on here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507959/what-is-the-definition-of-cohens-f-in-anova
I'd think that that post can help you further. However, I think that there is no equation that directly transforms Cohen's d to Cohen's f, as different parameters are required respectively.
